# HTML page template or easy repeat of code

Tags: javascript, html, css, templates

So I have been working on my website today, and I want certain features to appear on every page, such as the footer with copyright symbol, the general layout, the subscribe bar etc. so that I can create a new page, quick link in the "template", and then just ad content to the content section.

I have a javascript running my navigation menu on every page but just bringing 1 line of code for the menu into each page. But I would like a similar thing for the general template

Is it possible to do this?

I cant use php because github doesnt run php.

Cheers

EDIT:

```html
 <div class="copyright-container">
  <div class="vert-align">
   <p class="headline">Copyright &copy; 2017 RyanTeaches - All Rights Reserved.</p>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: You could use `.load` https://api.jquery.com/load/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you can create a Javascript file that appends everything you want to `body` when document is ready. But it won't be perfect as using PHP's `include`.

An example using jQuery to append the footer:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("body").append("<footer> © All right reserved. 2000-2017 </footer>");
});
```

Comment: forgive my naivety, I am new to coding in general - I have never used Jquery. I have updated my question with a bit of code I want on all pages. I presume I place all of it in the "" in your code section above. Do I place your code in a .js file, and link it into the pages I want it in with a <script> tag?

Comment: `document.body.innerHTML += '<div class="copyright-container"><div class="vert-align"><p class="headline">Copyright &copy; 2017 RyanTeaches - All Rights Reserved.</p></div></div>';` Will work for you

Comment: Where do I put that code though? in a .js file? How do I then link it into my pages?

Comment: Create a new .js file, like `general.js`. Then, on each page, you link the file like this: `<script src="general.js"></script>`. Please note the `src` attribute is relative, so change it by your path.

Comment: Best practice for `script` tags is to be found at the end of your file, right before the closing `</body>` tag. But, as you create DOM elements, you can include it in the `<head>` too for it to load quicker.

Comment: Ahh, I have figure it - mostly - however it does not keep my formatting - my "copyright-container" class should set it to a bottom: 0; so its always at the bottom, but when using the script, it doesnt seem to keep it at the bottom?

Comment: `bottom: 0;` is a CSS property. if you want it to be always at the bottom of the script (note - bottom of the SCREEN, not the page), you can use `position: fixed; bottom: 0;`.

Comment: Actually no - my bad, it does keep it there when there is more content! Many thanks, much appreciated!! :D